# Can java.net.http.HttpClient talk to a unix socked?

Tags: java, http

I'd like to use `java.net.http.HttpClient` instead of `curl` to perform the http examples list here:

https://docs.docker.com/engine/api/sdk/examples/

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-Java-code-to-generate-this-curl-HTTP-Get-request maybe this helps

Comment: There are a few [unofficial Docker libraries](https://docs.docker.com/engine/api/sdk/#unofficial-libraries) for Java, maybe it would be easier to use them instead?

Comment: @Marcono1234: I'm happy to accept that as an answer.

Comment: There is an [enhancement request agasint the JDK](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8275838?page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels%3Aworklog-tabpanel) to add this feature.  Unfortunately it's not possible to upvote or watch JDK issues, but perhaps some future readers of this issue will click on the link to find it's been implemented.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The JDK does not support Unix Domain Socket connections yet ([JEP 380](https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/380) will add this feature). But regardless of that it appears `java.net.http.HttpClient` only supports URIs (but not `SocketAddress`) as destination, therefore it would not work anyways.

There are however libraries which offer this functionality:

- [junixsocket](https://github.com/kohlschutter/junixsocket) ([relevant issue](https://github.com/kohlschutter/junixsocket/issues/79))
- [Reactor Netty](https://projectreactor.io/docs/netty/snapshot/reference/index.html#_unix_domain_sockets_4)
- Netty: [How do I connect to a UNIX domain socket running an HTTP server using Netty?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58455529)
- [unix-socket-factory](https://github.com/gesellix/unix-socket-factory) (for [Apache HttpClient](https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/index.html))

However, since your goal is to connect to Docker, it would be easiest to use one of the available [Java Docker clients](https://docs.docker.com/engine/api/sdk/#unofficial-libraries).